# the usage of the definite article

Tags: definite-articles

Dorothy lived in the middle of **the** great Kansas prairies.

---

1)Why is the definite article used in front of "Kansas prairies"?

2)What does the adjective "great" mean in this sentence? It means "big prairies"?

Answer (score 1):

The definite article "the" means the particular, well-known grasslands of the state of Kansas.

"Great" means large extent.  If you don't believe me, try driving all 424 miles of the length of Interstate Highway 70 from one end of the state to the other.  I have.